# Can I get scope by class?

Tags: angularjs, scope, destroy

I need to destroy a particular part of DOM and scope.

```
$(".panel_block:last").remove();
```

remove() didnt delete scope.
Can I get scope **by class** to use destroy()?

Comment: you may want to have a look at **[ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the scope of an element by using the following code:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('foo')).scope()
```

[Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) some documentation for `getElementByClassName()`

Comment: Thank you very much! I did it like angular.element($(".panel_block:last")).scope()